# Styling a Facebook company page

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

It has been a long time since I have developed content in Facebook, so I would like some information about styling a company page, or whatever it's called (Fan page maybe?).

Last time I did this, I used FBML. But as far as I know, its deprecated and replaced by HTML which is iframed in.

Do you still create an application, and style its canvas page?

Or where do the users land when they visit the page? Should I design a page on an external url, with the correct width, and iframe it in? I'm pretty lost here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple to create a new tab for your Fan page. Just follow this tutorial on creating one.  If you already have hosting you can be up and running within the hour (depending on how much coding will go into your iframed content).

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

What's great about these tabs, is you can set one as the default to be seen when a visitor comes ot your fan page.

Comment: Okay thanks! Followup question: Can i make the users land on a custom page instead of the wall?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned above, set your new page tag as the default tab in the page settings.